# Running Abaqus with AceGen

Tags: finite-element-method, acegen

I am an AceGen/AceFEM user, but I think codes generated with AceGen could be more useful if people accustomed to Abaqus could also use them. The AceGen help claims that generation of Abaqus codes is possible. I have generated the simplest possible case (linear elasticity) to check, whether it will run in my case. The problem is that the generated code contains statement: `include 'sms.h'`, and I don't have any idea where such a file can be found?
Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no experience with using Abaqus with AceGen generated subroutines, but you can find `sms.h` file (one of them) in AceGen installation directory: `FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "AceGen", "Include",
   "ABAQUS", "sms.h"}]`.

Comment: Since it seems that my comment did the job, I have it into an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Various files needed for compilation (e.g. `sms.h` file) of AceGen code to other numerical environments such as ABAQUS can be found in AceGen package installation directory. One example is:

```
FileNameJoin[{$UserBaseDirectory, "Applications", "AceGen","Include","ABAQUS"}]
```

This procedure is also documented in tutorial `FEAP - ELFEN - ABAQUS - ANSYS.nb`.